# How to configure Assembla service in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, assembla

I'm trying to integrate Assembla issue tracker with GitLab CE. Assembla project template has only 2 configuration option: Subdomain and Token. Subdomain seems clear. Where can I find the Token value?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a token when you go to your profile under `API Applications & Settings` or use this link with your subdomain:

https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.assembla.com/user/edit/manage_clients